# Error when installing SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server-2012-express

When I attempt to install SQL Server 2012 Express, I get an error

[image]

However, I have installed service pack 1. BTW, I am using windows 7.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that you're trying to install 64bit Sql Server on 32bit Windows 7. Other than that, make sure you right click and choose "Run as Administrator" when starting the installer, and that your copy of Windows evaluates as "genuine".

Sql Server also requires .Net and PowerShell, but if either of those were the problem I would expect to see a different error, or even just a prompt to allow them to be included with this installation.

Comment: thanks, however, when I choose Run as Adminstrator, still the same error and I am sure I use the correct version of the sql server

Comment: Tried restarting and then doing what Joel said? Also what is your error?